# SMS Text message - do line breaks count as characters?

Tags: sms

I'm developing a system to integrate with an SMS API, and I was wondering whether or not newlines count towards the character limit, I can't find any documentation on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it does. **ANY** character you embed in the message counts against the limit, whether it's "visible" or not. Even if it's not a printable character, you've still sent that character across the cell network and caused the cell network to use up (as they claim) vast amounts of bandwidth that much be charged ludicrous rates to handle.

Comment: 1 line break counts for **2 characters**.
Source: http://www.autotext.com.au/press-release/how-many-characters-sms-message

Comment: A detailed explanation - http://notes.acpmasquerade.com/post/82090102547/simple-english-explanation-for-sms-count

Answer (score 5):

Any character counts toward your SMS limit. Line breaks, included.

I actually can't find a standard or anything. But I do know the message size is limited to 160 7-bit characters, 140 8-bit characters, or 70 16-bit characters, depending on the alphabet used.

Sorry, I can't give you any sources.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested it on my phone. Yes, a line break counts

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each line break, space and carriage return adds to your character count.

1 space = 1 character

1 line break = 2 characters

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. also as a side note, i noticed that if there are any unicode characters in the text, the entire message is treated as unicode and the length of the message is multiplyed by three.